# Permanent serial connection to Raspi

Tags: serial, arduino

I can connect an arduino by serial to my laptop no problem using Processing.  Is a Raspberry Pi likely to be able to maintain a permanent USB serial connection to the arduino, or am I likely to encounter any issues?  Grateful for any advice from anyone who's tried this.

Comment: I plan to keep a permanent serial connection live to the rpi, I cant imagine why it would fail? I have   installations that lasted for many years on similar devices

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot report of a connection to an arduiono I'd like to try an answer nonetheless (after all a serial USB connection is involved).

I am using a RaspberryPi (Type B /w Archlinux) with an USB-RS485-serial adaptor to connect to a solar cell rectifier. System uptime is 50+ days by now and serial connection has been working since then. I don't see any reasons as to why the RPi should not be able to maintain a permanent connection.

During setup and early stages I encountered a broken connection only once. usbcore failed to register the device driver back then. After updating and rebooting it worked fine again (and therefore I did not do any in-depth investigation of the reasons).

Comment: Thanks Ghanima. Also, welcome to the forum. I'll see if anyone else with Arduino experience can contribute before closing